# Datadog's lambda log forwarder changes function name to lowercase

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, datadog

I have followed the Datadog's documentation ([here](https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/amazon_web_services/?tab=roledelegation#manual)) for manually configure AWS account with Datadog. Set-up includes a Lambda function provided by Datadog ([here](https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/guide/send-aws-services-logs-with-the-datadog-lambda-function/?tab=awsconsole)) which is triggered by Cloudwatch log group and lambda pushes logs to Datadog.

Problem is that when logs are pushed, Datadog's log forwarder lambda changes name of function, tags and rest of the  to small case. Now, when I use '!Ref ' while creating query for Datadog monitor using Cloudformation, then query contains autogenerated name of lambda which is mixture of small and upper case alphabets. But query does not work as Datadog changes name of the function while pushing logs.

Can someone suggest the work around here?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [Cloudformation macro](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cloudformation-templates/tree/master/aws/services/CloudFormation/MacrosExamples/StringFunctions) to transform strings in your template, in this case using the `Lower` operation to make your `!Ref`s lowercase. Keep in mind that you need to [define and deploy macros as lambdas](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html).

Comment: I tried that already. Macro's InputString does not accept intrinsic functions like !Ref <lambda-name>. It only supports parameters and stack metadata.